# Milestone plan for spring roo

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, spring-roo

I had been persistently trying spring roo since its milestone release until three months ago.

With the new STS release, I am about to try mucking around with it again. But, hold on, I am not about to waste my time again.

Preamble:
The last time I tried Spring Roo, it was a totally dysfunctional, especially the GWT and GAE integration part. Spring Roo was on an advertising path effectively saying "Finally a spring and gwt integration". I feel that that advertisement is misrepresented.

Questions:

1. Has anyone actually succeeded in creating a working GWT integrated project using spring roo?
2. It has been six months, and Spring Roo still cannot do GWT beyond a simple example and, therefore, still does not fulfill that advertisement. Is there a road-map towards achieving a GWT deployable spring roo? In agile management, we have road maps we try to think will get us where we want to be in a time frame we hope to conform to. I would like to see a road-map for deployable GAE and GWT integration, because I would like to put in place technology plan for my projects.
3. Should I abandon considering spring roo due to absence of a publicly available road map and wait for another two years before reviewing roo again?
4. Should I tell my cooperatives and associates (and anyone interested in my opinions) not to consider using roo as a deployable gwt and gae integration technology until another two years'?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you should be considering an alternative.

I'm not sure how you came up with "another two years".  No one of us, Spring included, knows the precise answer.

Comment: 2 yrs was what it took -eclipse, netbeans and .net to be usable. Don't buy a Ford with a new engine design until 2 yrs after its introduction. Two years to make a marriage workable. Two years before your baby stops waking you up at night. Two years ... etc.

Comment: It didn't take IntelliJ that long to be usable.  My marriage worked right off the bat.  My babies both stopped waking me up after nine months.  Your comment is pithy and poetic, but quite wrong.